# Impossible to split line in two parts with QGIS tool 'Split features'

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

I'm willing to cut a line in two parts with QGIS.

So I enabled **Snapping** and I wanted to use the **Split Features** tool, like I've seen anywhere: one first left click and then another left click on the vertex I choose in order to draw a red line and then right-click to finish the process and split the line.

But it doesn't work properly!

The first picture is what I do with the split features tool, and the second is what I get.

[image: Split Features]
[image: The result]

Could someone please explain to me why I'm obtaining that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you tried the tool on another layer or feature? Have you tried without selecting the feature? Have you tried without snapping enabled?

Comment: The problem was that the line was multi-part. That's why it didn't cut the entire line.

Comment: If the line has a self-intersection, when you perform a split the line will be split at the self-intersection as well as where you drew the split.

Comment: @csk is there any way to make a line with self-intersections NOT split at all self-intersections and only into two segments where you preform this tool?

Comment: @jamierob I don't know. Ask a new question.

Comment: While this isn't directly related to multi-part geometries, it looks like this could be related to a long standing bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/14070